# Find the value of $f(1/4)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Suppose $f: D=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \vert z \vert <1 \} \rightarrow D$ is analytic and $f(0)=0$ and $f(1/2)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}+i\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$. Find the value of $f(1/4)$?

I check $\vert f(1/2)\vert=1/2$,but how I can use this result to find the value of $f(1/4)$?

Answer (score 4):

You apply the Schwarz lemma to deduce that $f(z)=az$ for some $a\in S^1$. Since $$f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac1{2\sqrt2}+\frac i{2\sqrt2},$$what must be the value of $a$? Then $f\left(\frac14\right)=\frac a4$.

Comment: Very nice by the way!!!

Comment: $a$ can be found from $f(1/2)=a/2$ and given value of $f(1/2)$

Comment: @1256 That's the way of doing it. In this case $a=\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}$.